# Checkboxes and text not aligned

Tags: html

In the following HTML, as the text is too long my goal is to have the text align below the previous line's text.

When I do the following, the check box is on one line and the text is below that.

My goal is to have the check box and the next be on the same line. If the text is too long, the text should wrap below the previous line.

```
<div style="float:left;margin-right:10px">
    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkOption1" runat="server"/>
</div>
<div style="float:left">
    <b><u>Option 1</u></b> - Attend in person. This is the best way to gain critical knowledge and express your thoughts and opinions.   
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

Here is what the HTML code looks like:

```
<div style="float:left;margin-right:10px">
    <input id="chkOption1" type="checkbox" name="chkOption1" />
</div>
<div style="float:left">
    <b><u>Option 1</u></b> - Attend in person. This is the best way to gain critical knowledge and express your thoughts and opinions. Ample time will be provided for individual discussions during breaks and at the networking reception. 
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

Comment: You tagged your question HTML, but I can't read this as HTML. Please give us the final generated HTML output. I can't read ASP, and don't intend to learn soon.

Comment: Wrap the checkbox and text in the same div, style with CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap both the checkbox and the text in the same `div` element. Then you have a few options.

I'd also recommend styling with CSS instead of `style=` tags.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EHss7/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="option">
    <input class="chkbox" id="chkOption1" type="checkbox" name="chkOption1" />
    <div class="text">
        <div class="head">Option 1</div> - Attend in person. This is the best way to gain critical knowledge and express your thoughts and opinions.  Ample time will be provided for individual discussions during breaks and at the networking reception. 
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.option{
    float: left;
    display: block;
}

.chkbox{
    margin-right: 10px;
    float: left;
}

.text{
    float: float;
}

.head{
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: left;
}
```